# Convexity over a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, convex-analysis

First post on math.stackexchange! I have a question which probably requires a bit of Differential Geometry knowledge which I'm lacking.

By definition a convex function over a vector space $V$ is such that $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y)$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and $x, y \in V$. Two ways to check convexity are:

1. Compute the Hessian and verify that it is positive semidefinite everywhere
2. Check that $\frac{d^2 f(x+ty)}{dt^2}\mid_{t=0} \geq 0$ for all $x, y \in V$

Even though these two are equivalent, sometimes I feel it is a bit easier to use the second condition.

Now, if we define convexity over a manifold similarly to $(1)$, i.e. the Hessian is positive semi-definite everywhere, then what a natural equivalent of $(2)$ would be? I guess some additional term will pop-up because of the curvature of the manifold? Or if we differentiate similarly along a geodesic would be fine?

Just a reference would be enough, thanks.

Comment: I take it that by "manifold" you mean "Riemannian manifold"?

Comment: Yes @EricWofsey, thanks for noting that.

Comment: It is not really that the curvature shows up, but that you need to use the metric to define the Hessian already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We say that $f : M\to \mathbb R$ is a [geodesically convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity) function if

$$f\circ \gamma$$

is convex (in the usual sense) for all geodesic $\gamma$. This is the same as

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} (f\circ \gamma) (t) \ge 0$$

for all $t$. Now we compute

$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} (f\circ \gamma) (t) = \nabla_{\dot\gamma} \langle \nabla f ,\dot\gamma\rangle = \langle\nabla_{\dot\gamma} \nabla f, \dot\gamma\rangle= Hf(\dot\gamma, \dot\gamma),$$

where $Hf$ is the hessian of $f$ given by

$$Hf(X, Y) = \langle \nabla_X \nabla f, Y\rangle.$$

Thus in this sense (1) and (2) are also equivalent: $f$ is geodesically convex if and only if $Hf$ is semi-positive definite.