# Notion of convexity in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-geometry

Consider the set of (smooth) function on a generic differential manifold (let's say without boundaries). What kinds of additional structures on the manifold are sufficient and/or necessary to be able to speak of the "convexity" of a function – besides making the manifold a convex set, ie giving it a flat affine connection?

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505936/455507) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06373) discuss geodesic convexity, based on a connection or on a metric structure, but I was wondering if other alternatives have ever been discussed in the literature, especially non-metric- and non-connection-based ones.

Please give some references with your answers, so I can explore further!

Comment: The fact is: how would you define "being between two points" in a path connected space which is not metric?

Comment: @Didier that's indeed a question implicit in mine. I don't see how, bit I can't exclude some mathematician found an ingenious way to bypass that (just like the notions of flatness or geodesic turn out not to require a metric, just a connection). That's why I'm asking. Mathematics is a beautifully surprising subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comments are necessarily speculative, since the question amounts to "Is there a non-metric structure giving rise to a notion of *convxity*?", and I'm arguing "probably not".

Think first of a real interval. Convexity is not detectable by the smooth structure alone: For example, if $I = (0, 1)$ and $f(x) = x$, then $g(x) = f(x^{2})$ is strictly convex, and $h(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$ is strictly concave. These examples all but imply that some notion of *distance* is essential for defining convexity.

Inspired by Didier's comment, on a path-connected space we might impose a structure, "For every pair of distinct points $p$ and $q$, there exists a unique *disinguished path* joining $p$ and $q$." (On a Riemannian manifold of non-positive curvature, such as a flat affine space, geodesics would be the standard choice.) For brevity, let's call this a *DP structure*.

Whatever the notion of *distinguished*, one expects an "extension principle" of the type: If $r$ lies on the distinguished path from $p$ to $q$, then the distinguished path from $p$ to $r$ is the restriction. (If this is not the case, then *distinguished* is not locally-defined.) That means that for each point $p$, there is a family of maximal distinguished paths through $p$, whose union fills the entire space, and such that two maximal distinguished paths through $p$ intersect precisely at $p$.

An *automorphism* of a DP structure would be a diffeomorphism inducing a bijection on the set of distinguished paths. On the assumption that a DP structure induces a notion of convexity on some class of real-valued functions, convexity of any particular function $f$ is invariant under automorphisms of the DP structure. But the examples above indicate how rigid an automorphism of our hypothetical DP structure must be: Effectively affine in some sense.

To emphasize, this isn't a definitive analysis: I'm not asserting that no "non-metrizable DP structure" exists. But offhand, I would not expect such a structure to exist.

Comment: Thank you for the reasoned analysis. I'd say that the (tentative) conclusion is that we need at least a notion of affine transport, rather than distance? Affine transport automatically introduces a sort of distance (or rather, measure) along paths, but in such a way that distances along different directions cannot be compared. Your 1D example is a degenerate case of this.

Comment: Philosophically (and tentatively), "yes" to affine transport/affine structure. <> Another observation: Convexity is characterized by "triangles with a bottom vertex", in the sense that if $r$ is "between" $p$ and $q$ for some definition of _between_, then $(r, f(r))$ is "below the secant from $(p, f(p))$ to $(q, f(q))$". That looks like a potentially more direct way to axiomize convexity than the notion of "distinguished paths".